# How to get Monday and Sunday of last week

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, calendar

If today is November 28, 2021, I want to get last week's Monday and Sunday like:

```
Monday: 2021-11-15
Sunday: 2021-11-21
```

I tried like this:

```py
today = datetime.date.today()
idx = (today.weekday() + 1) % 7
self.monday = (today - datetime.timedelta(7 + idx - 1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
self.sunday = (today - datetime.timedelta(7 + idx - 7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But the output is like this, which is wrong:

```
Monday: 2021-11-22
Sunday: 2021-11-28
```

It is correct if today's date is November 29, 2021.

How will I be able to achieve this?

Comment: for last week Sunday days offset, use a timedelta of `(today.weekday() + 1) % 7 + 7` days, `today.weekday() % 7 + 7` for last week's Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take today's date and subtract 1 week plus today's weekday 'number':

```
today = datetime.date.today()
today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday(), weeks=1)
```

For the Sunday before that, use `days=today.weekday() + 1`

Comment: It returns 21 and 20.

Comment: I've made setting `today` explicit, but for me it returns `datetime.date(2021, 11, 15)`

Comment: The updated answer works for me now. Many thanks !